# How to take input array of N elements without defining size in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic-memory-allocation

Input: In the input, there will be an array of N element

Output: Output will be the number that is the sum of its left and right sub-arrays.

Example
Input:
2 3 5 20 5 3 2

Output:
20

Input:
5 10 20 122 30 12 9 36

Output:
122

Anyone can explain this question how it will be solved as I am applying logic as the output will be the middle element of the array but is this true logic. Also, for increasing the size of an array at runtime we can use ArrayList but how it will be declared can anyone suggest code. Thank you.

Comment: I think he/she required only logic programming language doesn't matter.

Comment: Divide and conquer: Split the large and complex problem you're trying to solve into smaller and less complex sub-problems. Continue to do this division into even smaller and simpler sub-problems until none can be divided anymore. Then solve each little and by then quite simple problem, one by one. Putting them together to solve the larger and more complex sub-problems, until you have solved the original complex problem.

Comment: Besides that, please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don 't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: How will ArrayList be declared? SO is not a place you come to, so that others can do your homework for you. I'm pretty sure if you googled: "arraylist  java usage" you would get a lot of helpful results.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to find the element which is equals to the sum of its right and left elements.
Below program should achieve the same.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 5, 10, 20, 122, 30, 12, 9, 36 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            int sum = 0;
            if (i == 0) {
                // first element simple sum the right elements
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    sum += arr[j];

                }

            } else {
                // sum the right elements
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    sum += arr[j];

                }
                // sum the left elements
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    sum += arr[j];

                }
                // check if sum of left and right elements equals element.
                if (sum == arr[i]) {
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code will work for declared inputs but I want to take input from the user can you please explain how it will take from the user. Thank You.

Comment: You can use scanner class of java. Please find the link which contains example that can be modified to suit your needs. https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-get-input-from-user-in-java

Comment: In scanner class, we have to define array size to take input from the user and in for loop also we are using the size of the array. For auto increment in size, how can we achieve that with scanner class?

Comment: https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-accept-array-elements-find-sum/

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to just calc the total sum and subtract every number from it in array and when after substraction of ith no from total sum gives again that ith number means this number is equal to sum of all other right and left subarray

```
l=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
x=sum(l)
y=0

for i in range(len(l)):
    y=x-l[i]
    if(y==l[i]):
        print(l[i])
        break;
```